# I can't use a param in this XML select statement

Tags: xml, select, param

I have this XSLT1.0 code:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//Labels/CounselPoint"/>&#160;<xsl:value-of select="StudentTalk1M/@StudyPoint"/>&#160;
```

I have now changed my method to have a param called Class. So I wanted to do:

```
            <xsl:value-of select="//Labels/CounselPoint"/>&#160;<xsl:value-of select="StudentTalk1{$Class}/@StudyPoint"/>&#160;
```

Visual Studio does not like it. How do I use a param in my statement?

This is calling code:

```
<xsl:call-template name="Display_AYTFM">
     <xsl:with-param name = "Class" select ="M" />
</xsl:call-template> />
```

This is part of the method:

```
<xsl:template name = "Display_AYTFM" >
  <xsl:param name = "Class" />
  <div class="containerAYFM">
```

Comment: Well which type of value (string, number, boolean, node set, result tree fragment) have you bound to the parameter?  How does your input XML look? Which value do you want to select?

Comment: I have updated the main topic.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute value templates allow you to embed expressions within ordinary attributes, for example

```
<chapter id="chap{$n}">
```

You can't use this syntax to embed an expression inside another expression - the select attribute of `xsl:value-of` is already an expression, so you can't use curly braces within it in this way.

Now, I'm finding it difficult to correct your syntax, because I don't really know what you had in mind. I guess that since your original code had

```
StudentTalk1M/@StudyPoint
```

and your new code has

```
StudentTalk1{$param}/@StudyPoint
```

then perhaps you have elements called StudentTalk1A, StudentTalk1B, StudentTalk1C, etc, and you want to parameterize which of them you are selecting. That would be a horrible way of misusing XML, but if you really need to do this, you can write

```
select="*[name()=concat('StudentTalk1', $param)]/@StudyPoint
```

Comment: You understood my need. But, I don't really know what would be bad practice. I decided in the end to have a xsl:choose method and xsl:when clauses and I just used the StudentTalk1 etc directly. It is not what I really wanted though. I was hoping in the end to pass in parameters like "StudentTalk1" and "StudentTalk1A" and then those be used in the select statement. So would this be OK: select="*[name()=$Student]/@StudyPoint ????? From what you are showing me. I could just use that? Would that be a horrible way to misuse XML?

Comment: Also, what does the * represent before the [? My node Is local to the current node.

Comment: * matches any element regardless of name

Comment: The bad design pattern I'm referring to is using names with an internal syntax that carries information, e.g. address-line-1, address-line-2, address-line-3. It's much better practice to use `<address-line nr="1">`.

Comment: Ok. So if I am on a specific node in the XML and want to access the value of a sub node, based on the param passed, I can just use [node()=$param]? The * would not be needed. That is my understanding.

Comment: I think you need to do some reading. Making up syntax and asking here whether it will work is not a productive way forward. An expression in square brackets is a predicate and is used to filter a set of nodes. It has to have a set of nodes to filter, and "*" is a good set to start with, it selects all children of the context node. And if $param is a name, you don't want to compare it with the content of nodes, you want to compare it with their names.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation! Yes, I will try to find a suitable resource on XSL.